# Artificial limitation in games?

Tags: graphics, hardware

I've made a research and found out that without dedicated graphics games use max 50% of each processor's core. And it seems to be an artificial limitation. For a  powerful processor 50% is a very big number compared to a powerful graphics card.

> So if you could buy 1 car engine vs. 10 motorcycle engines that apply twice the power for half the cost and weight, which would you buy?

I dont need your long lectures about the cpu and gpu architectures You cant answer the simple question why I must buy 10 motorcycles when I already have an universal car (processor) fastened with prediction and loaded only at 50% that can turn into 10 motorcycles and a car. And by the way today motorcycles (gpus) costs almost as much as cars (cpus)

> Sure, some people and companies write inefficient code.

There is no problems to make a code which will use 100% of a processor's capacity.
So it is rather the artificial limitation than unwilling.

Comment: So you've made research? Can you show us that research? You don't seem to be that well-versed in game development or software development in general, so perhaps you misunderstood something.

Comment: FWIW, you would get a more beneficial experience out of the site if you registered. That would allow you to have dialogues with other users instead of this one way communication.

Comment: As written, this post doesn't ask a question or pose a problem to be solved. If you want to respond to a previous post, you should do so as a comment on that post. If you need help merging/reclaiming accounts you can get help with that [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

> why I must buy 10 motorcycles when I already have an universal car (processor) fastened with prediction and loaded only at 50% that can turn into 10 motorcycles and a car.

Because it can **not** turn into 10 motorcycles. Some tasks run very fast on GPU and others very fast on CPU. Calculating a typical GPU task like a pixel shader on the CPU might be possible in theory, but in practice it will run extremely slow. So the FPS gain from moving GPU tasks to the CPU when CPU load is available would be negligible. We are talking about orders of magnitude like 40.4 FPS vs. 40.5 FPS here.

Explaining the reasons why would require a long lecture about the cpu and gpu architectures which you explicitly rejected to read, so you have to just accept that as a fact.

And what is the cost for you for that tiny, unperceivable FPS gain?

- It would require a lot of programmer work to implement that. I might have made it sound easy above to just move a task from the GPU to the CPU, but in practice it is not. Those programmer-hours could alternatively be used to improve the gameplay or graphics.
- There will be more bugs, because a hybrid GPU/CPU rendering pipeline would make a lot of things a lot more complicated.
- Your CPU will run hot when it permanently runs on 100% load, which decreases its lifespan.
- It would cause your CPU to use more power, which increases your electricity bill.

So it's not worth the cost. Neither for your game experience nor for your wallet.